# Why does file appear empty when it's clearly not?

Tags: python

This is the code (sorry if I did it wrong I have no idea how to do that):

```
with open( 'output', 'r' ) as f:
    print("this is line one: " + f.readline(1))
```

And this is what it prints:

```
this is line one:
```

I have checked the file so many times the one says "0". I've checked it in vscode. I've checked it by just opening it in the folder it definitely says `0`, but it is just not working and yes it's on line 1.

I've looked all over google and stack overflow and nothing is at all helpful when it comes to my question.

Comment: Get rid of the argument to `readline()` so it can read the entire line rather than just the first character of the line.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add explanation for the answer above, from python [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html) of `readline`

> f.readline() reads a single line from the file; a newline character
> (\n) is left at the end of the string, and is only omitted on the last
> line of the file if the file doesn’t end in a newline. This makes the
> return value unambiguous; if f.readline() returns an empty string, the
> end of the file has been reached.

where its argument is similar to the `size` argument of the `read` function:

> size is an optional numeric argument. When size is omitted or
> negative, the entire contents of the file will be read and returned

Meaning: when you passed 1 the the `readline` function you actually read 1 byte from the line, instead of reading the entire line. when passing no arguments, the entire line is returned as a string up to the newline character `\n`

Answer (score -1):

```
with open('output', 'r') as f:
    print("this is line one: " + f.readline(1))
```

`readline` does not take an argument, but `readlines` takes  a size (`readlines(size:int`) argument.

Though in your case you want to read one line, so `readline()` should do fine.

```
with open('output', 'r') as f:
    print("this is line one: " + f.readline())
```

Comment: I am not sure readline does not take an argument. look at file `typing.py` where the method is declared as follows for class `IO`:

    def readline(self, limit: int = -1) -> AnyStr:

Comment: Yes, running `help` on `readline` yields `readline(size=-1, /) method of _io.TextIOWrapper instance`.

Answer (score -1):

The syntax `file.readline(size)`  read from the file a string of that size. If no argument is specified the readline() method will return the entire line from the given file.
So your function should be:

```
with open( 'output', 'r' ) as f:
   print("this is line one: " + f.readline())
```

If you want to read all the lines in the file you can modify the function to this:

```
with open( 'output', 'r' ) as f:
    for count, line in enumerate(f):
        print("Line {}: {}".format(count, line))
```